# Change screen resolution into Kali on Mac BookPro

Tags: linux, dual-boot, kali-linux, graphics, macintosh

I installed Kali in dual boot on my Mac Book Retina, all work, but I have a screen resolution too high.

So I need to change the screen resolution, but if I change it, the screen become black, and then I have to force turn off.

How can I fix it??

**EDIT:**

Kali is 1.1 version, while my mac is a mid 2012..

I installed the nvdia driver, and after that I can set only 2880 x 1800....

Comment: Please provide more information on the OS Version and Screen resolution .

Comment: Also the specific nvidia driver

Answer (score 1):

run the command

`xrandr`

It will give you list of available resolution. Choose any one of them and execute the command

`xrandr -s <choosen_resolution>`

e.g. "xrandr -s 1024x768"

Though, this command will work till X-session last. This is not reboot persistent. If you want to make permanent changes then you need to modify Xorg configuration file.

Comment: I tried, but nothing change! Black screen yet...

Comment: I installed nvidia driver, and now if I run xrandr I can only set up 2880 x 1800 as resolution....

Comment: This only works if the mode exists already

Answer (score 1):

If your desktop environment is gnome then you can install and run gnome tweak tool

```
apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then go to Windows > Window scaling and increase the value.

This article has some more tips relating to high pixel density / retina displays on linux http://www.pcworld.com/article/2911509/how-to-make-linuxs-desktop-look-good-on-high-resolution-displays.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way with mbp is to change the Master Boot Partition to REMOVE EFI and go with Legacy MBP.